# How to create lines/stops relationship

Tags: sqlite, database-design

I'm not a database expert and I'm simply building a prototype app, so nothing really important.

Anyway, the app is about a subway: this subway has many lines and sometimes some stops are **shared** between lines (so, for example, stops 3 and 4 are stops of lines 2, 7 and 9).

So, I made up a SQLite `stops` table:

```
    +---------+-------------+------+
    | Field   | Type        | Auto | 
    +---------+-------------+------+
    | id      | integer     | YES  |
    | name    | varchar(20) | NO   |
    | lines   | ?           | NO   |         
    +---------+-------------+------+
```

What's the best way to deal with shared stops? My idea was to create a `lines` table and then in the lines field of the `stops` table put a comma separated list of `lines.id`. I don't know why, but I feel there could be a better way.

Any suggestion is appreciated, and sorry for the really noob question.

Comment: I strongly vote against the CSV idea.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I'm here just to listen to other ideas   :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would keep it simple and use a table `lines` which has an ID (primary key) along with other metadata for a line (such as `name`):

**lines**

```
(id, name)
```

Then, create a table for the stops:

**stops**

```
(id, name)
```

Finally, you can create a bridge table which will connect lines with stops:

**bridge**

```
(lineId, stopId)
```

Each record in the `bridge` table represents one line having a given stop.

Note that using CSV to represent a line having multiple stops is totally *not* the way to go here, as it renders the powers of your relational database useless.

**Update:**

If you want to record the position of a stop in a given line (and assuming that positions would differ across lines), you could use the following table:

**stopNumbers**

```
(lineId, stopId, stopPosition)
```

The stop position can be obtained knowing the line's ID and the stop's ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need a many-to-many relation, which is stored in a separate table like this:

```
table lines_to_stops
line_fk
stop_fk
```

That's the relational world ...

Note that records in the database are not in any specific order. If you need to put the stops into any specific order (which you most probably do), you have to store this order to the database as well:

```
table lines_to_stops
line_fk
stop_fk
order_in_line
```

Comment: I know records are not in a specific order, of course   ;-)   Moreover, you can't change the id of an autoincrement field, so if they remove or add a stop to a line, you can easily end up pulling your hairs if you haven't another field. Sorry for the simple question, but I don't "play" with databases since more than 10 years.